# hclust order and cutree groups in R

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I want to create a data frame that has my row names, their order according to `hclust`, and their group membership according to `cutree`. I'm having a hard time reconciling the outputs from these functions.

```
d <- dist(USArrests)
hc <- hclust(d)
pheatmap::pheatmap(as.matrix(d)[hc$order, hc$order], cluster_cols = F, cluster_rows = F) # what I expect to see

data.frame(
  state = hc$labels,
  hc = cutree(hc, h = 0), # hc doesn't match heat map
  family = cutree(hc, k = 5) # family order doesn't agree with hc order
)
```

Based on my understanding of hierarchical clustering, `hc` and `family` should both be in the same order. For example:

```
hc     = 1 2 3 4 5 6 # smallest to greatest
family = 1 1 2 2 2 3 # smallest to greatest
```

**Update:**

This gets me the result I'm looking for, I want to see if there's a simpler way to do this

```
data.frame(state = hc$labels[hc$order],
  row = 1:length(hc$labels),
  family = cutree(hc, k = 5)[hc$order]
)
```

Comment: Maybe `hc$labels[hc$order]`

Comment: That seems to match the heat map, now how do you get the `family` column to match up?

Comment: Maybe `cutree(hc, k = 5)[hc$order]`

Comment: So `tibble(state = hc$labels[hc$order], order = 1:length(hc$labels), family = cutree(hc, k = 5)[hc$order][state])`

Comment: @GKi your solution seems to work, I wonder if there's an easier way to get this result

Comment: Maybe `data.frame(state = hc$labels, row = seq_along(hc$labels), family = cutree(hc, k = 5))[hc$order,]`